# Сгенерировать url до нужного файла в php

Tags: php

Задача.

Есть скрипт, расположенный в папке `/var/www/site.com/folder/index.php`. Он вызывается по адресу `site.com/folder/index.php`. Также имеется папка с файлами по адресу `/var/www/site.com/folder/files/`. В ней, предположим, имеются следующие файлы: `file1.ext & file2.ext`.

Как мне сгенерировать автоматически url адреса к этим файлам?

П.С.: Надо полагать, что папка folder может меняться, так как скрипт будет ходить по рукам. Точно известно положение папки files относительно файла index.php (возможно, в конфигах).

Возможно ли написать такой вариант, где в коде не будет записей типа "`site.com/folder/`"?

Comment: Непонятно задан вопрос вообще... Как я понял в итоге вы хотите видеть примерно следующий url
`http://example.com/759ec3548ec9a8488cb5c172b3a4ebb5/file1.ext`

Comment: Нет, я хочу без изменений кода кидать в любую папку свой скрипт и чтобы ничего не ломалось и ссылки на скачивание файлов корректно формировались.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo dirname(substr(__FILE__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))).'/files/file1.ext'
```

Генерация относительного url.

Answer (score 0):

Если всё, как вы описали, то вроде бы ничего сложного:

```
<?php
$d = dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/");
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/files/";
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    echo $path.$entry.'<br>';
}
$d->close(); 
?>
```

Или так (в общем, равносильно):

```
if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/")){
    $path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/files/";
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))){
        echo $path.$entry."<br />";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

P.S. Забыл добавить, что в начале будет выводить точку или две. Посему можно сделать проверку перед этим:

```
//...
if($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
    echo $path.$entry."<br />";
}
// или
if(strlen($entry) > 2){
    echo $path.$entry."<br />";
}
//...
```

Comment: А где папка folder?